# ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification in this code

Tags: oracle

Create trigger ittriggs before insert of salary on itempls for each row

The above code is to create a trigger that prices and user define error message and does not allow insertion
I couldn't create trigger using this code i don't know what mistake is in it

Comment: You insert a row, not a column. So either `before insert on itempls` or `before update of salary on itempls` or `before insert or update of salary on itempls`.

Comment: Which database do you use? Is it MySQL, or Oracle?

Comment: I use Oracle database 21c(SQL plus)

Comment: OK. Now post code of the entire trigger and exact error message you got (i.e. not explained in your own words; Oracle errors have their code).

Comment: Thanks,littlefoot but thanks to Thorsten kettner i correct the code

Comment: Anyway this the code
SQL> create trigger ittriggs before insert of salary on itempls for each row
 2 declare
 3 triggsal itempls.salary%type;
 4 begin
 5 select salary into triggsal from itempls where eid=12;
 6 if(:new.salary>triggsal or :new.salary<triggsal) then
 7 raise_application_error(-20100,'Salary has not been changed');
 8 end if;
 9 end;
10 /
  What is try to do is TO CREATE A TRIGGER THAT RAISES AN USER DEFINED ERROR MESSAGE AND 
DOES NOT ALLOW INSERTION